# How to combine multiple conditions into one if statement in PHP (for Joomla)

Tags: php, joomla

I have a couple questions regarding PHP... please keep in mind I am pretty new to PHP and understand only the very basics.

I would like to know how to condense something this (the countModules is a Joomla function):

```
    if($this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C') == 0) $modRow2 = " hidden";
    if($this->countModules('Top2A or Top2B or Top2C') >= 1) $modRow2 = "";
```

Would it be something like this?

```
    if($this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C') == 0) {
    $modRow2 = " hidden";
    }else{
    $modRow2 = "";
    }
```

Or for that matter, could I combine (there are possible columns, and if only two are shown, I need $modCellRow to = "col2"):

```
    if($this->countModules('Top1A and Top1B') >= 1) $modCellRow1 = "col2";
    if($this->countModules('Top1B and Top1C') >= 1) $modCellRow1 = "col2";
    if($this->countModules('Top1A and Top1C') >= 1) $modCellRow1 = "col2";
```

into this:

```
     if($this->countModules('Top1A and Top1B') >= 1) or ($this->countModules('Top1B and Top1C') >= 1) or ($this->countModules('Top1A and Top1C') >= 1) {
     $modCellRow1 = "col2";
     }
```

Any advice? Am I doing this right?

**////// UPDATE ///////**

Would all this be correct?

```
$topModCont1="";
$modRow1="";
$modCellRow1="";
$modRow2="";
$modCellRow2="";
$bottomModCont1="";
$modRow3="";
$modCellRow3="";
$modRow4="";
$modCellRow4="";
$modRowFooter="";
$modCellRowFooter="";

$countModsCont1=$this->countModules('Top1A + Top1B + Top1C + Top2A + Top2B + Top2C');
$countModsRow1=$this->countModules('Top1A + Top1B + Top1C');
$countModsRow2=$this->countModules('Top2A + Top2B + Top2C');
$countModsCont2=$this->countModules('Bottom1A + Bottom1B + Bottom1C + Bottom2A + Bottom2B + Bottom2C');
$countModsRow3=$this->countModules('Bottom1A + Bottom1B + Bottom1C');
$countModsRow4=$this->countModules('Bottom2A + Bottom2B + Bottom2C');
$countModsFooter=$this->countModules('Footer1A + Footer1B + Footer1C');

if($countModsCont1 == 0) { $topModCont1=" hidden"; }
if($countModsCont2 == 0) { $bottomModCont1=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 0) { $modRow1=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 1) { $modCellRow1="col1"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 2) { $modCellRow1="col2"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 3) { $modCellRow1="col3"; }
if($countModsRow2 == 0) { $modRow2=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow2 == 1) { $modCellRow2="col1"; }
if($countModsRow2 == 2) { $modCellRow2="col2"; }
if($countModsRow2 == 3) { $modCellRow2="col3"; }
if($countModsRow3 == 0) { $modRow3=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow3 == 1) { $modCellRow3="col1"; }
if($countModsRow3 == 2) { $modCellRow3="col2"; }
if($countModsRow3 == 3) { $modCellRow3="col3"; }
if($countModsRow4 == 0) { $modRow4=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow4 == 1) { $modCellRow4="col1"; }
if($countModsRow4 == 2) { $modCellRow4="col2"; }
if($countModsRow4 == 3) { $modCellRow4="col3"; }
if($countModsFooter == 0) { $modRowFooter=" hidden"; }
if($countModsFooter == 1) { $modCellRowFooter="col1"; }
if($countModsFooter == 2) { $modCellRowFooter="col2"; }
if($countModsFooter == 3) { $modCellRowFooter="col3"; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to assign `$this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C')` to a variable.

That's just for some readability.  As for the PHP or statement, we use a double pipe `||` for that, not the word "or".

Also, note that $this->countModules() using 'and'/'or' in the parameter will return true or false, not the number of modules counted.  If you want to count the total number of modules, you should use the '+' operator.  (Just read that on http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/countModules, so correct me if I am wrong :) )

So at the end of the day...:

```
$modRow2=""; //give it an initial value, then you don't need an else branch to give it this value, only a single if-statement to change it.  

$modCellRow1="";  //also initialize this, for the same reason

$countMods=$this->countModules('Top2A + Top2B + Top2C'); //count total modules
if($countMods == 0) 
{
    $modRow2 = " hidden";
}
if ($countMods==2) 
{
    $modCellRow1="col2";
}
```

This code could be cleaner but I thought it might be better to keep it simple and readable instead.

Hope this helps! :)

EDIT:

Your update looks fine (after a quick read) :) Just a side note on the duplicate if-statements though, you could rather use switches instead - they make for cleaner code.  For example:

instead of

```
if($countModsRow1 == 0) { $modRow1=" hidden"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 1) { $modCellRow1="col1"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 2) { $modCellRow1="col2"; }
if($countModsRow1 == 3) { $modCellRow1="col3"; }
```

use

```
switch($countModsRow1)
{
   case 0:
      $modRow1="hidden";
      break;
   case 1:
      $modCellRow1="col1";
      break;
   case 2:
      $modCellRow1="col2";
      break;
   case 3:
      $modCellRow1="col3";
      break;
   default:
      //do something if none of these cases are evalutated as being true
      break;
}
```

It might look like a ton of code, but if your if-statements were to grow for some reason, they might become difficult to manage in the future.
Some resource on the switch if you feel the need to read up on it: [PHP Switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

EDIT:

You were then correct initial post: to check if there are modules in each position (not worrying about how many there are), you would use something like `$this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C')`.  If that evaluates to 0 (false), then there are no modules in those positions, otherwise there is at least one module in EACH position.

If you want to check if there is a module in one or more of those positions, you would use `$this->countModules('Top2A or Top2B or Top2C')`.  If that evaluates to 0 (false), then none of those positions contain modules, otherwise AT LEAST one of then does.

I hope that helps a bit more, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Check out the update to my main post... does all that look right? Anything I can do to condense it further without making it too complicated?

Comment: Edited my post :) That switch statement might not be the most condensed code, but it's good practice and makes your code more maintainable in the future.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea there's just one problem with the way I was counting modules... if there is more then one module in a module position, it counts towards the total. Which means if Top1A has three modules in it, it will end up displaying all three of my columns (i.e. "col3" for the css class).. which is NOT what I want if they are all in the same module position. I need to check if there is something in each position, not how many modules there are in total inside each of the positions.

Comment: Edited my post again, sorry for the confusion :) Hope the minor change in my latest update is what you're looking for.

Comment: You could use a ternary but one of the goals in a template is readability so you might want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C') == 0) $modRow2 = " hidden";
if($this->countModules('Top2A or Top2B or Top2C') >= 1) $modRow2 = "";
```

you can use like this as well

```
$modRow2 = $this->countModules('Top2A and Top2B and Top2C') == 0 ? " hidden" : "";
```

[Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Thanks, I "think" I understand? You are using more of a shorthand? "?" is the operator to let it know I'm making the statement and ":" is the for else?

Comment: @TCDFactory yes it is, i already attached the link for more information about it.

Comment: Check out the update to my main post... does all that look right? Anything I can do to condense it further without making it too complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use if($this->countModules('Top1A') >= 1 && $this->countModules('Top1B') >= 1)) { do what you want }else{}.

Comment: Yea I need it to check all logic statements... if A&B = 1, if A&C = 1, if A&C = 1... because if there are two that = 1 then I need two columns... after that one I'll have another that checks all three and if all three = 1 then I'll have it display as three columns.